# How can I cut the string

Tags: bash, command, cut

**This is my log file**

```
 
Started by user [[^8mha:////4Ogh/8s/t6WCscPP1xh6+eb52nXryfTykwZL/ZyDxeq/AAAAlx+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQTGjNKU4P08vOT+vOD8nVc83PyU1x6OyILUoJzMv2y+/JJUBAhiZGBgqihhk0NSjKDWzXb3RdlLBUSYGJk8GtpzUvPSSDB8G5tKinBIGIZ+sxLJE/ZzEvHT94JKizLx0a6BxUmjGOUNodHsLgAzWEgZu/dLi1CL9xJTczDwAj6GcLcAAAAA=^[[0madmin
```

**My code**

```
echo "Job User= $(cat /home/kaanmrzl/log.txt | grep "Started by user" | cut -d"[" -f5 )"
```

**Output**

```
 Job User= 0madmin
```

**what i want is output**`

```
 Job User= admin
```

Comment: Jenkins created this log file. Actually i have to cut according to this part "^[[0m" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like that:

```
echo "Job User= $(sed '/^Started by user/s/.*=^\[\[0m//' /home/kaanmrzl/log.txt)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(if you are ok with `awk`, tested with given samples).

```
awk -F"\\[\\[" '/^Started by user/{print substr($3,3)}'  Input_file
```

This code removes first 2 characters from 3rd field where field separator is set as `[[`  by `awk` code's `-F`.

Comment: This code doesn't work or I couldn't run it, code output is  = awk: warning: escape sequence `\[' treated as plain `['
awk: fatal: Unmatched [ or [^: /[[/

Comment: @KaanMurzoğlu,not sure which version of `awk` or which shell you are using, it worked  fine for me, when I checked it in bash

Answer (score 0):

Using your code you just need to add one more line:

```
CORE=$(echo $(cat /home/kaanmrzl/log.txt | grep "Started by user" | cut -d"[" -f5 ))
IDUSER=$(echo "Job User =" ${CORE:2})
```